# How to show a json object returned from the server

Tags: javascript, json, frontend, axios, backend

How can I get the JSON object that my backend is sending in my frontend code when the HTTP status is not 200?

When my backend is sending a 200-response I'm able to show the returned JSON data by doing this:

**backend**

```
res.status(200).json({status: 'Information found'})
```

**frontend**

```
.then(data => console.log(data.status)) // Information found
```

However when I'm trying to do the same with a 400 or 404 status I can't get the returned JSON.

**backend**

```
res.status(404).json({error: 'No information found'});
```

**frontend**

```
.catch(error => console.log('Error from backend', error))
```

**result**

[image]

I first tried error.error but that's undefined.

What is the difference with the 200-status return and how can I get the message that I'm sending from the backend in my frontend?

**EDIT**

**Frontend**

```
    axios.post('https://firebaselink.net/getTestData', { id: orderNumber })
        .then(data => console.log(data.status))
        .catch(error => console.error(error))
```

**Backend**

```
  export const getTestData = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    cors(req, res, () => {
      const id = req.body.id;

      admin.database().ref(`data/${id}`).once('value')
        .then(snapshot => {
          if(snapshot) res.status(200).json({status: "Information found"})
          else res.status(404).json({error: "Information not found"})
        }).catch(error => res.status(500).json({error: 'Internal error}))
    })
  })
```

Comment: How is front end promise created?

Comment: The answer would depend on the library you're using to make the request. What are you calling .then() on?

Comment: @Hodrobond don't know what browser you're using but `console.log(a)` works just fine for me

Comment: @AlFarnsworth, added some more code

Comment: Not to derail your question but you don't appear to be adding any extra information to the response body that cannot be inferred from the response status, ie 404 = "not found", 500 = "internal server error", etc.

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960 and https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors

Comment: Voting to close as a typo / no longer a problem / RTFM

Comment: Thanks @Phil - error.response.status is doing the job!!

Answer (score -2):

**Q:** I tried error.error but that's undefined. How do I print my error?

**A:** `Javascript` is untyped, meaning an `object` can be anything. The best solution here would be to do a `console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2)` to see what property it has and then access to print out the message.

An `error` object would typically have the `message` property.

**References**:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error

Comment: `console.error(error)` (or as OP has it `console.log('Error from backend', error)`) should produce just as much information (if not more) than putting the object through `JSON.stringify`

Comment: FYI @Phil the initial posting does not contain the code `console.error`,

Comment: `console.log`, `console.error`, doesn't matter; the latter just makes it red

Comment: Unreasonable. Initial posting about `error.error` which resulted in `error` property been undefined. Thus the solution to inspect the object's property to see what is there without knowledge of either `console.log` or `console.error` been used.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Just to clarify, OP has `console.log('Error from backend', error)`. This would show at least the same amount of data as `console.log(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2))` but would also include any methods and transient data. Your answer therefore provides less information than OP was already privy to

Comment: As described in comment. My solution would have review to the author that his error message is in the path `response.status` path. @phil @Thore